# path coverage in for programs in assembly language

Tags: testing, assembly, x86, automated-tests

I have a lot of assembly code and I want to test them automatically. Test must be done in all paths of programs. Is any tool or program that test x86 assembly language programs automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There are no tools that "test programs automatically".

First, somebody must specify what is to be tested (usually the program functionality, sometimes the program's performance).

Then some test framework needs to be built that will allow the targeted software to be exercised in a way that the test can be executed and test results collected.

Finally some specific tests (desired input, expected outputs) need to be coded using the framework.

In your case, you insist on executing "all the paths through the code".

First, that's a LOT of paths, in any realistic application.  It may be so many that you can't enumerate them all, let alone build tests for each path.  As a practical matter, people doing path testing find a way to eliminate a lot of the paths (e.g.,  if there is a DO loop, only check paths for zero and one transitions of the loop).

Second, just *finding* paths in assembler can be very hard.  Where does a JMP indirect go?
(This means any path analysis likely requires a points-to analysis to support it).  Worse, if some code is manufactured into a buffer and executed, what does it doe an where does it go? [In fact, sometimes in assembler you can't really tell what is an instruction vs. what is data].

Third, you'd need some tooling that can identify such paths, so that you could verify your tests exercised them.  These tools are exceeding rare as far as I know.  I think there is practically nothing that is available for assembler.

So, you likely have to plan on building your own tools for this, if you are serious about "all paths" testing.  That will be expensive and time consuming.  It may be necessary depending on your delivery requirements.